# Add max Whitelist mint check per user

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-client, candy-machine-v2

I need to put a check on Max whitelisted NFTs. Like each user can mint 10 NFTs. Any rust code snippet or reference would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Candy Machine v3 introduced a feature called "Candy Guards", which are basically configuration settings that can be applied to a Candy Machine.

Two guards that may be relevant for your use case are the "Allow List" and "Mint Limit" guards.

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/available-guards/allow-list

> The Allow List guard validates the minting wallet against a predefined
> list of wallets. If the minting wallet is not part of this list,
> minting will fail.

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/candy-machine/available-guards/mint-limit

> The Mint Limit guard allows specifying a limit on the number of NFTs
> each wallet can mint.